# Why dill.dump of a list of dictionary (81,000,000 bytes) takes forever?

Tags: python, dictionary, dump, large-files, dill

I have produced a list of dictionary of 8100000 bytes, with 9 million+ elements. Each element has a dictionary of 32 pairs of value and key, though the same set of keys is used in each element.

I wanted to save it for future analysis. I have tried dill.dump, but it took forever (more than 1 hour) that I had to interrupt the kernel. This is suppose to be fast and easy, right?

Here is what I have tried:

```
import dill
output_file=open('result_list', 'wb')
dill.dump(result_list, output_file)
output_file.close()
```

I also tried pickle and bzip2

```
import bz2
import pickle
output_file=bz2.BZ2File('result_list', 'w')
pickle.dump(result_list, output_file)
```

But ran into memory error.

Any tips on making this feasible and less time consuming?
Thanks!

Comment: try [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) dump

Comment: just tried and updated the question

Comment: see this [benchmarks](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/python-serialize/)

Comment: What is the content of your dictionary? Maybe you have large keys and/or values. Dill is also capable of complex serialisations of classes and functions, so if you're serialising objects that are instances of user-defined objects that could also slow things down.

Comment: ... or if it's something that's built on large `numpy` arrays... there's a lot of objects that take a while.  `dill` has `dill.settings`, which allows you to pick the flavor of serialization, and that can often make a difference on how much is actually stored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the `dill` author.  You may want to try `klepto` for this case.  `dill` (actually any serializer) will treat the entire `dict` as a single object... and something of that size, you might want to treat more like a database of entries... which is what `klepto` can do.  The fastest approach is probably to use the archive that treats each entry as a different file in a single directory on disk:

```
>>> import klepto
>>> x = range(10000)
>>> d = dict(zip(x,x))
>>> a = klepto.archives.dir_archive('foo', d)
>>> a.dump()
```

The above makes a directory with `10000` subdirectories with one entry each in it. Keys and values are both stored. Note you can tweak the serialization method a bit as well, so check the docs to see how to do that for your custom case.

Alternately, you could iterate over the dict, and serialize each of the entries with dump inside a parallel map from a `multiprocess.Pool`.

(Side note, I'm the author of `multiprocess` and `klepto` as well).

**UPDATE: as the question was changed from serializing a huge dict, to serializing a huge list of small dicts... this changes the answer.**

`klepto` is built for large `dict`-like structures so it's probably not what you want then.  You may want to try `dask`, which is built for large `array`-like structures.

I think you could also iterate over the list, serializing each of the list entries individually... and as long as you loaded them in the same order, you'd be able to reconstitute your results.  You could do something like store the position with the value, so that you can restore the list and then sort if they got out of order.

I'd also ask you to think if you have your results could be restructured to be in a better form...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. After a closer look at my data, it turns out to be a list of dictionary (rather than a dictionary), with 9 million+ elements. Each element has a dictionary of 32 pairs of value and key, though the same set of keys is used in each element. It seems that `klepto.archives.dir_archive` only works with dict? I have updated my question too.

Comment: I managed to transform my data to a pandas dataframe with 9 million rows * 32 columns, and with `df.to_pickle("result_dict.pkl")`, it was super fast. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Hi @MikeMcKerns! Can `dill` be used to solve this problem?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430747/6907424

Comment: @hafiz031: as a first approach , you can try replacing `multiprocessing` with `multiprocess`.  The latter uses `dill`.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate? I am not quite sure how do I maintain a dictionary with `dill` such that I can hold non picklable objects in them and share across processes. Question link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430747/6907424